# Convert into DD-MON-YYYY format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar column with value such as 2020-07-05T00:00:00.000+0000 and i wish to convert the same in DD-MON-YYYY in oracle i.e 05-JUL-2020.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the times always midnight, and the time zone always GMT?

Comment: Why do you store TIMESTAMP values as **string**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are not dates but timestamps with a time zone. Don't use `TO_DATE` because you will be discarding a lot of information and potentially getting the wrong date when you discard the information. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` instead.

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' )
FROM   your_table
```

Then if you really want to naively convert the timestamp to a string and discard the timezone information without applying it to the date then just use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' ),
         'DD-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
       )
FROM   your_table
```

However, you probably want to normalise the time-zone and convert all the timestamps to a common time-zone (i.e. UTC) and need to use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' )
           AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'DD-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
       )
FROM   your_table
```

So, for some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_column ) AS
SELECT '2020-07-05T00:00:00.000+0000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-07-05T00:00:00.000+0100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-07-04T23:00:00.000-0100' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the options above:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' )
         AS timestamp,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' ),
         'DD-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
       ) AS ignore_timezone,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM' )
           AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'DD-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
       ) AS utc_date
FROM   your_table
```

Will output:

> ```
> TIMESTAMP                    | IGNORE_TIMEZONE | UTC_DATE   
> :--------------------------- | :-------------- | :----------
> 2020-07-05T00:00:00.000+0000 | 05-JUL-2020     | 05-JUL-2020
> 2020-07-05T00:00:00.000+0100 | 05-JUL-2020     | 04-JUL-2020
> 2020-07-04T23:00:00.000-0100 | 04-JUL-2020     | 05-JUL-2020
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46d5335e614412985a8356dff9533a4b)*

Answer (score -1):

Convert to a date using `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(substr(col, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I see no reason to convert this back to a string, but if you really want, you can then use `to_char()`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1cf069afeeace8ec5cb0db5b39719ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @lobh This will ignore the time-zone information and may not give the correct answer if you expect the output "date" to be in a common time zone (i.e. UTC+0).

Comment: @MT0 . .  This looks like a case where the OP happens to have a string in a particular format and just wants to extract the date.  I don't see a need to take that into account, given the question.

Comment: @lobh . . . Unless you really need to take the timezone into account (which your question doesn't specify), then this is the simplest answer.  In my experience when I've needed to deal with data like this, the timezone has not been relevant.